# iOS12 sirishortcut- successfully donated interaction but unable to find in sir&search in settings under App

Tags: swift, xcode10, ios12, sirishortcuts

Can We donate siri shortcut for system Intents?

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can donate shortcut. After did some R&D on this , I am giving answer to my question. :)

Comment: How did you solve this? I am trying to donate a customised system intent and when I do so I get no errors but can't see my app in the Shortcuts app.

Comment: There is a delegate method to intent handler in AppDelegate. We need to implement this.